# Display a loading icon until Firebase firestore fully loads data into a textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

How do I go about implementing a loading icon while my app loads firebase firestore data into it? Right now, when I load in the app, it shows an empty textview, and once it's got the data from the database, it pops up. I'd like there to be a loading screen until the data is fully loaded into the activity before displaying, so there's no data pop-in.

I've tried to look at other solutions on this website but they're all from different programming languages or difficult for me to understand.

This is my simple code for getting data from a database, and storing it in a textView.

```
    welcomeTv = findViewById(R.id.welcomeTv);
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    fStore.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                username = task.getResult().getString("username");
                welcomeTv.setText(username);

                //other stuff
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Currently logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ProgressBar` and call `ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to hide the progress bar once the data is loaded.

First add a `ProgressBar` outside of the rest of your layout and set the **visibilty** of the layout you want to hide to **gone**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"> // Initially hide all the body

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logOutBtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84000003" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logOutBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log out"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And once the data is loaded hide the ProgressBar and make the mainContent layout Visible

```
ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar); // Get ProgressBar reference
ConstraintLayout mainContent = findViewById(R.id.mainContent);
welcomeTv = findViewById(R.id.welcomeTv);
fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


fStore.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide Progress bar 
            mainContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show TextView

            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                username = task.getResult().getString("username");
                welcomeTv.setText(username);

                //other stuff
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Currently logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

**Update:** Updated the code with your layout mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, RelativeLayout doesn't work with my solution so I'm using ConstraintLayout, Is there a way to make everything in the activity invisible until the textview has loaded in the data? Right now the progressbar is behind a logout button, but would like the user to not be able to see anything until the progress bar has loaded in data. Thank you.

Comment: Sure.You can do it the same way as with TextView. Just wrap everything you want hide in a ConstraintLayout and give it an `id` and set Visibility to gone.  Then get the reference to the layout using the id and call `setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)` on this layout once data is loaded.

Comment: @AadilFarooq Updated the answer with your layout code. Try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly how I wanted it, your help is really much appreciated! I do have a side question regarding a splash screen, if I can discuss it with you I'll be in your debt! :)

Comment: So I have implemented a splashscreen which is the Main and Launcher as you do, but when the splashscreen comes on, for a brief moment it gets pushed up into the notification bar and comes back down. I think it's similar to the problem this person is having: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/385 changing android:windowBackground to android:background does nothing for this unfortunately.

Comment: Please share a video of your issue and better add a new question with more details instead of comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205342/discussion-between-aadil-farooq-and-susheel-karam).

Answer (score 1):

Add [SweetAlert](https://jitpack.io/p/Leogiroux/sweet-alert-dialog) in your project. So when your data is loading you can put your sweetalert.

Use following Library :

```
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
```

When you fire event for load data start the sweetalert then it will close when data in received

```
//Global Declaration
SweetAlertDialog pDialog;

pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
pDialog.setTitleText("Loading");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
fStore.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                username = task.getResult().getString("username");
                welcomeTv.setText(username);

                //other stuff
            } else {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog.dismisswithAnimation();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Currently logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
});
```

Comment: Just tried this,   implementation 'com.github.Leogiroux:sweet-alert-dialog:' does not work but 
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.6.2' which I found on a Youtube video does work. I'm getting an error on the pDialog's which says "Variable 'pDialog' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final".

Comment: make it global variable.

Comment: Thank you, I've got it working, little correction on your solution: dismisswithAnimation should be dismissWithAnimation. You can still see the data pop-in in the background with this sort of loading, is there a way to make it a full page loading, then once it's loaded, the page loads in. Because right now, you see the page for a very brief moment, then the loading dialog opens, then it closes once the data has loaded in.

Comment: can you provide full code then i provide full proper code

Comment: my layout: https://pastebin.com/da4zm015

code: https://pastebin.com/K5s8NyMa

Comment: so you want progress bar on before and after mAuth ?

Comment: I think the Auth is an integral part of that page as it only works if the user is logged in, I'm not too sure if it makes a difference if it before or after the mAuth?

Comment: you can directly change it to easy way. Check [this](https://pastebin.com/XZ7g7VCz). Why you need AuthStateListener ? Just put inside onStart(). Means any time user starts the app it will check first

Comment: Your method might be better for this than what I implemented, I've put the code you put in pastebin in my onStart method, getting 'non static method cannot be referenced from a static context' on getCurrentUser() however

Comment: @AadilFarooq well you received your answer.

Comment: Thank you, your code was much better than what I had for my mAuth, if I could I would +1 for you